# Change speed of animation using animator.play in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

how can I change the speed of animation using animator.play("clip");

without using animation["clip"].speed = xf;

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly change the speed for the entire `Animator` using  [Animator.Speed](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-speed.html)?

```
animator.Speed = xf;
animator.Play("clip");
```

advantage is that you can have multiple `Animator`s using the same `AnimationClip` but with different velocities.

Comment: Ok let me try this